# Can not load XML document containing &commat; entity

Tags: c#, xml

Can you please let me know how to resolve this problem:

XML file:

```
<ref ref-type="sectiona">sdsadsd <email>EffectiveHealthCare@ahrq.hhs.gov</email>sdasd  &commat; Sec asdd</ref>
<ref ref-type="sec">test Sec</ref>
<ref ref-type="sec">seesdasdasd <email>EffectiveHealthCare &commat; dasdasdasd</email>asdad Sec</ref>
<ref ref-type="sec"> Sec</ref>
```

My code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocFile = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocFile.Load("xmlfile");
```

Exception

> Reference to undeclared entity 'commat'. Line 35, position 65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this xml nodes

```
<ref ref-type="sectiona"><![CDATA[sdsadsd <email>EffectiveHealthCare@ahrq.hhs.gov</email>sdasd  &commat; Sec asdd]]></ref>
<ref ref-type="sec">test Sec</ref>
<ref ref-type="sec"> Sec</ref>
<ref ref-type="sec"><![CDATA[seesdasdasd <email>EffectiveHealthCare &commat; dasdasdasd</email>asdad Sec]]></ref>
```

nodes that contain invalid values must be escaped `<![CDATA[....]]>`

Comment: there is any another way to resolved it without useing <![CDATA[....]]>

Comment: hi can you tell mi how to dynamically updated CDATA in xml file & when we found "&commat;" in xml node using c#